# Is there a way to run advanced AD searched via CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, active-directory

Long story short, I frequently have to look up users in Active Directory by their phone number. I usually do an advanced search as follows:

Field: User > IP Phone Number

Condition: Ends With

Value (Last 4 digits of phone number)

Is there a way to do this same search via CMD? My plan is to set up a batch script where you just have to put in the last 4 digits and it will show the results - which I will have no problem creating - just not sure if it's possible to do this search through CMD.

Comment: DSGET OR DSQUERY should help.  I also like Joeware's ADfind http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/index.htm

Comment: With Remote Server Administration Tools installed [you can use powershell](http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2013/02/searching-active-directory-with-powershell-and-a-users-phone-number.htm).